# Call method from other applications on the same server

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a web application where users can see their created tasks from a database.

I want to build a second application that calls all entries of the database and checks if the task is still up-to-date or expired. I am looking for a solution where my second application can force all sessions of my first application to reload their data.

Is there a way to call a method that can effect all running sessions?

```
public void callUpdate()
{
//get running Sessions of App1    
//send update event
}

public void EventListener(updateEvent)
{
//reload data
}
```

or something like this?

This image may help to understand the problem:

[image]

I've also looked for solutions with web services and servlets but I didn't find something that could help me with my problem. Or I didn't use the right keywords when searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JMS solution which would loosely couple the applications.  webApp1 could send a message (CheckForExpiredTasks) to a Queue which triggers the task checking.  webApp2 would listen for that messages and, when received, perform the work which looks for expired tasks.  If the scenario arises where you want to expire the running sessions, webApp2 sends a "ExpireAllSessions" message to a Queue.  webApp1, listening on the right Queue, would receive this message and expire all of it's running sessions.

Using JMS would be nice, in that it doesn't matter whether the two applications are deployed.  As long as they can get to the data.  webApp2 wouldn't need to be a webApplication, per se.  Just a light services application using EJBs or Spring.

Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks for the tip with JMS. Its like you said a nice solution^^.